# Bootstrap table get data from selected row

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-table

I have created an bootstrap table (see image )

[image]

this table is populated by an mysql connection with php server side.

My problem is to get data from selected row in a table, i know I have to use function

> bootstraptable('getselections')

But I receive this

> getSelections: [object Object]

intead of this

> getSelections: [{"Nation":"dad","Site":"-"}]

Please can you help me?

Full code here

```
<div id="toolbar">
            <button id="button" class="btn btn-default">getSelections</button>
        </div>
<table id="table" data-click-to-select="true" 
                data-toggle="table"
               data-toolbar="#toolbar"
               data-height="600"
               data-click-to-select="true" 
               data-url="db_list.php"
               data-search="true"
               data-pagination="true"
               >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="num"  data-checkbox="true" >#</th>
                <th data-field="Nation">Nation</th>
                <th data-field="Site">Site</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

               </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $table = $('#table'),
        $button = $('#button');

    $(function () {
        $button.click(function () {
            alert('getSelections: ' +  $("#table").bootstrapTable('getSelections'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What does getSelections[0] gives you? Since you are printing in alert thus it is giving output like that. Just do `console.log('getSelections: ',  $("#table").bootstrapTable('getSelections'))`

Comment: @SujataChanda i receive this message : getSelections:  w.fn.init [table#table]

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Bootstrap Table getSelections example](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/methods/getSelections.html)

It uses JSON.stringfy function. So you have to use as follow.

```
alert('getSelections: ' + JSON.stringify($("#table").bootstrapTable('getSelections')));
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't use JSON as data-url to populate my table

Comment: if i do this i receive this : ` getSelections: {"0":{"jQuery331073420158381058982":{"width":600,"height":600,"showColumns":true},"jQuery331073420158381058981":{"hasDataAttrs":true}},"length":1} `

Comment: Um .. Please show your getSelections method code of bootstrap-table.js file.

Comment: ` BootstrapTable.prototype.getSelections = function () {
        var that = this;

        return $.grep(this.options.data, function (row) {
            // fix #2424: from html with checkbox
            return row[that.header.stateField] === true;
        });
    };
`